# Подсчет количества элементов в подколлекции

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Всем привет
Я пытаюсь подсчитать количество элементов в своей "подколлекции" и пока что у меня выходит неверно, можете подсказать?
У меня есть коллекция, в ней 2 поля и ещё одна коллекция - задача в том чтобы узнать сколько элементов во вложенной коллекции?

```
public class DetailSection
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<DetailItem> Items { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
    }
```

Я пробовал 2 подхода, оба неверные, подскажите где я ошибаюсь?

-1-

```
private void DetailedData(IEnumerable<DetailSection> detailedViewResultSection, IXLWorksheet worksheet, string currency)
        {
            var res = detailedViewResultSection.Where(x => x.Items.Count());
}
```

-2-

```
var res = detailedViewResultSection.Select(x => x.Items.Select(s=>s.AccountNumber).Count());
```

Но все неверно

Comment: если вы используете `Where` (например, отфильтровать по кол-ву), то внутри у вас должно быть усковие, а не просто `Count()`, например, `Count() > 0`, если же вы хотите просто получить кол-во элементов, то используйте `Select`

Comment: `detailedViewResultSection.SelectMany(x => x.Items).Count()` ?

Comment: `detailedViewResultSection.Select(x => x.Items.Count()).Sum()`?